# How to read clock cycle from latency tables?

Tags: signature, implementation, performance

I see many papers that compare the latency of the signature schemes in terms of clock cycles by two-three numbers. I don't know why they write 2-3 numbers instead of one number to represent clock cycle. For example consider the following table from this paper link: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/122.pdf
[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with this question, however going through the paper, I have two comments about the paper a) if latency is important, why don't they use LMS instead?  and b) if they intend to use XMSS for attestation (the IOT device does the signing), how do they expect to do state management securely?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just like writing 6325 as 6,325. So that it's easier on the eyes when you have many digits.

Comment: A little sloppy writing, as we can see, after a little help from the $\LaTeX$ experts, it is quite possible to [write it in a good way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654369/62865) with the help of siunitx and column packages.